# Shiro filter authentication user error when user have logged in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, shiro

When I'm using AJAX and attempt to login I get a server response code 200 but when I try to access another URL, the Shiro filter always intercepts my request.

I'm configuring the filter in the `spirng-shiro.xml`.

This shows the user access, `login` is ok but the other url gets a 302: [get list url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkfSL.png)

```
function loginUser() {
    axios.post(`${FOO_API}/login`, {
        name: "foo",
        passwd: "123456"
    });
    console.log("1");
}

function getUserIndex() {
    axios.get(`${FOO_API}/list`);
}
```

Server controller, redundant code omitted:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public JsonResult login(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    String name = map.get("name").toString();
    String md5Pwd = new Md5Hash(map.get("passwd").toString(), name).toString();
    if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(name, md5Pwd);
        token.setRememberMe(true);
        try {
            currentUser.login(token);
            log.info("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() + "] logged in successfully.");
        } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
            uae.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return JsonResult.createSuccess("ok");
}

@GetMapping("/list")
public JsonResult getAll(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    System.out.println("user name: " + subject.getPrincipal());
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        System.out.println("cookie name: " + cookie.getName());
        System.out.println("cookie val: " + cookie.getValue());
    }
    return JsonResult.createSuccess(userService.getAll());
}
```

Spring-Shiro config, I'm only configuring one realm extending `AuthorizingRealm` and implementing one authentication method:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter"
    class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/api/users/login" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="/api/users/index" />
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized.jsp" />
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /api/users/login = anon
            /api/users/doLogin = anon
            /api/users/logout = anon
            /api/users/** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

@Override
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("get two");
    UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
    Map<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    String name = upToken.getUsername();
    map.put("name", name);
    User user = null;
    try {
        user = getUserService().login(map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catch me");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (user != null)
        return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user.getName(), user.getPasswd(), getName());
    return null;
}
```

---

#### update: change `filterChainDefinitions` value

```
    ....
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /assets/** = anon
            /api/users/login = authc
            /api/users/logout = logout
            /api/users/** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
   ....
```

user login OK. It will take another method be invoked when request `/api/users/login`

only login method make error when first login, just invoke this error method will be get real `/api/users/login`

[trigger another method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7owL.png)

full message

```
11:54:39.881 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc' processing OPTIONS request for [/api/users/login]
11:54:39.881 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/users/login
11:54:39.882 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public com.f.util.JsonResult com.f.api.controller.UserController.login(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
11:54:39.882 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'userController'
11:54:39.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'userController': ResourceElement for public com.f.service.UserService com.f.api.controller.UserController.userService
11:54:39.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'api.userService'
11:54:39.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'api.userService': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.f.dao.UserMapper com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.userMapper
11:54:39.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userMapper'
11:54:39.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
11:54:39.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'api.userService' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
11:54:39.883 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Creating CGLIB proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl@73316c84]
11:54:39.884 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'api.userService'
11:54:39.884 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'userController'
11:54:39.923 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
11:54:39.924 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
11:54:39.947 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.login]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
11:54:39.948 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1099897330 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] for JDBC transaction
11:54:39.948 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1099897330 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] to manual commit
11:54:39.950 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
11:54:39.950 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4f48efb3]
11:54:39.951 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1099897330 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] will be managed by Spring
11:54:39.951 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.f.dao.UserMapper.login - ==>  Preparing: select u.id, u.name, u.passwd, p.id p_id, p.project_name from users u left outer join project p on p.id = u.project_id 
11:54:39.951 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.f.dao.UserMapper.login - ==> Parameters: 
11:54:39.959 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.f.dao.UserMapper.login - <==      Total: 19
11:54:39.960 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4f48efb3]
11:54:39.961 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4f48efb3]
11:54:39.962 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4f48efb3]
11:54:39.963 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
11:54:39.963 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1099897330 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef]
11:54:39.964 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1099897330 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] after transaction
11:54:39.964 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 19
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:77)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:166)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.login(UserServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$79b2f5ea.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e9f3d2c.login(<generated>)
    at com.f.security.MyRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(MyRealm.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:571)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:274)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:260)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AuthenticatingFilter.executeLogin(AuthenticatingFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter.onAccessDenied(FormAuthenticationFilter.java:154)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onAccessDenied(AccessControlFilter.java:133)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.AccessControlFilter.onPreHandle(AccessControlFilter.java:162)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.isFilterChainContinued(PathMatchingFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.PathMatchingFilter.preHandle(PathMatchingFilter.java:178)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:131)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 19
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    ... 63 more
11:54:39.976 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc' processing POST request for [/api/users/login]
11:54:39.977 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/users/login
11:54:39.977 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public com.f.util.JsonResult com.f.api.controller.UserController.login(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
11:54:39.978 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'userController'
11:54:39.978 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'userController': ResourceElement for public com.f.service.UserService com.f.api.controller.UserController.userService
11:54:39.979 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'api.userService'
11:54:39.980 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'api.userService': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.f.dao.UserMapper com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.userMapper
11:54:39.980 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userMapper'
11:54:39.980 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
11:54:39.980 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'api.userService' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
11:54:39.980 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Creating CGLIB proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl@4f22ef0e]
11:54:39.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'api.userService'
11:54:39.981 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'userController'
11:54:39.983 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Read [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@50be15cd]
11:54:39.984 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.f.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.login]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
11:54:39.984 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1851398855 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] for JDBC transaction
11:54:39.984 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1851398855 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] to manual commit
11:54:39.986 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
11:54:39.987 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@386927e4]
11:54:39.987 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1851398855 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] will be managed by Spring
11:54:39.987 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.f.dao.UserMapper.login - ==>  Preparing: select u.id, u.name, u.passwd, p.id p_id, p.project_name from users u left outer join project p on p.id = u.project_id WHERE name = ? 
11:54:39.999 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.f.dao.UserMapper.login - ==> Parameters: foo(String)
11:54:40.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.f.dao.UserMapper.login - <==      Total: 1
11:54:40.010 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@386927e4]
11:54:40.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@386927e4]
11:54:40.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@386927e4]
11:54:40.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@386927e4]
11:54:40.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
11:54:40.011 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1851398855 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef]
11:54:40.014 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1851398855 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@399b2ef] after transaction
11:54:40.014 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
11:54:40.017 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  com.f.api.controller.UserController - User [foo] logged in successfully.
11:54:40.018 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  com.f.api.controller.UserController - "foo"
11:54:40.021 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [com.f.util.JsonResult@1f8078e2] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@50be15cd]
11:54:40.021 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
11:54:40.021 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not** actually **logging in** into your application and no session cookie is registered since you are using two completely different filters. Your login path is set to `anon`, discarding whatever you post to it, but your protected resource path is using the `authc` filter which requires the caller to be authorized or authorize now.

What currently is happening in your application is that when you are calling `api/users/list` Shiro is redirecting you to `api/users/login` since you are not authorized. It is expecting you to perform a POST, presenting your username and password, but receiving a GET, resulting in a 302 method not allowed.

The correct approach for a form-based login is to point your login path and your protected resource paths to the `authc` filter and the logout path to the `logout` filter. You can read more about default filters and how to use them in the official Shiro [documentation](https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#default-filters).

The following snipped should point your paths to the correct filters:

```
....
<property name="filterChainDefinitions">
    <value>
        /api/users/login = authc
        /api/users/logout = logout
        /api/users/** = authc
    </value>
</property>
....
```

Comment: seem meet a bug? It will trigger database service method whenever I'm first submit '/api/users/login', this one invoked service method get error

Comment: after debug found problem, Shiro login filter intercept firstly but don't passing controller so not get submit `name`  when I'm request `/api/users/login`