# Page Mapping not working

Tags: xml, hibernate, xhtml, shiro

I'm working on a project and when I login to my login page. It shows the next page but browser stays in the login.xhtml instead of test.xhtml.

Here where I think the problem is in the applicationContext.xml:

```
    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.xhtml"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/test.xhtml"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized.xhtml"/>

    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /login.xhtml = anon
            /test.xhtml = authc
            /unauthorized.xhtml = anon
        </value>
    </property>
```

Comment: Do you have controllers defined that are forwarding instead of redirecting? Was login successful?

Comment: Yes, login was successful but it still stays in the login.xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** actually **logging in** into your application and no session cookie is registered since you are using two completely different filters. Your login path is set to `anon`, discarding whatever you post to it, but your protected resource path is using the `authc` filter which requires the caller to be authorized or authorize now.

Read more about this issue in a similar question i answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969361/9647266).

This is the correct approch and fixes your issue:

```xml
<property name="filterChainDefinitions">
    <value>
        /login.xhtml = authc
        /test.xhtml = authc
        /unauthorized.xhtml = anon
    </value>
</property>
```

Please make sure to add the `logout` filter to be able to logout of your application. Also note that your configuration is missing the generalised `/**` filter path to protect all resources of your server.